# How to put wait with a specific conditions while implementing get request in rest-assured

Tags: java, rest, api, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Once I send GET request , I am able to get 200 OK.
In response body, there is a key, consider that is "field_name".
Currently "field_name" value is "start".After some time, value is changes to stop.

Expected O/P : want to run it till i do not get the "field_name":"stop" in response body.

Comment: So, you want to perform GET requests in a loop until value changes to `stop`?

Comment: @Fenio  yes! on a start basis it's value is start and after some time it changes to stop. So want to perform it till i do not get stop as a value of field_name

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Can your application make use of async behavior? If yes then take a look at AsyncHttpClients. AsyncHttpClients can wait for the result from the server and in your scenario can continue processing until the server does not return a "stop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `while` loop, perform `GET` request inside, get the status and put the `Thread` to sleep?

```
String field_name = "start";
while (field_name.equals("start")) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
    }
    Response response = when().get("my url").then().extract().response();
    field_name = response.jsonPath().getString("path.to.field_name");
}
```

In the above code, I assumed that `field_name` is `start`. 
The loop begins, we wait for 500 milliseconds and after that time, we perform `GET` request, extract its response and get the `field_name` value.

If the `field_name` value equals `stop` then the loop will no longer be executed. If the loop equals `start` then we wait for another 500 milliseconds, perform `GET`, get the status etc...

Hope it helps!